# Is there way to make my code to do some actions in another site and return the results?

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, keyword

I need to do an unordinary thing. I need to make my site to go to another site, write some words on the some input field, search results and get back the results of that search from another site.

Is there any way for it?

Comment: Does the other site have some kind of API?

Comment: The other site should have an available API for you to implement what you want to do.

Comment: You mentioned in your tags *web-scraping* - Is this what you actually want to do? If so, there are plenty of web-scraping tools out there - Just search for it.

Comment: All troube is that the site have not an api.

Comment: As @0xDECAFBAD says, you can use web scraping instead. However, this can be prone to breakages (if the remote site changes their HTML) or blocking (if you place too much load on their server they may refuse requests from your IP range).

Answer (score 0):

If you need automated tool then you have to code a script. With PHP you can use cURL. With cURL you can post data into forms and get content as you want. You can post data for exmaple:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

**Use an API**

Usually for stuff like this there should be an API for what you're trying to do.

If that is not the case check the following options AND make sure the owner of the website allows you to do what you want to do (or you could get blocked if you cause too much traffic or he doesn't like web-scraping in general)

**Use direct HTTP requests**

A web form is basically just a way to "build" a HTTP request to a certain endpoint. Look at the HTML of the website to figure out how the request is created:

- Check the "action" attribute of the form tag for the target url.
- Get the HTTP method by checking the value of the form tags "method" attribute
- Get the parameter names by checking the name attributes of all input tags.

If they change their website these values may change and your program may fail.

You can use cURL or any other HTTP library to do that.

**Use a library simulating a web browser**

Example: [Symfony Browser-Kit](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html)

I don't want to provide a whole manual of how to use it, since the documentation on the linked page is pretty good. But an example taken from that page:

```php
use Acme\Client; // Make sure to create this class as described in the documentation

// make a real request to an external site
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');

// select the form and fill in some values
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Log in')->form();
$form['login'] = 'symfonyfan';
$form['password'] = 'anypass';

// submit that form
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

If they change their website this could fail too, depending on the changes they made. You would need to update your program accordingly.